# How to "flatten" iframe to avoid window with two vertical scroll bars

Tags: html, css, iframe

On a page of my web app I include an iframe. The iframe typically has a pretty hefty height - let's say on the order of 1500px. What ends up happening, naturally, is that the window now has two vertical scroll bars and the scroll wheel scrolls one or the other depending on the position of the cursor. This can make for a slightly awkward experience at first.

What I simply want to do is "flatten" the iframe. I'd like it to stretch it to be the full height of it's contents, so that there is no need for a scroll wheel on it, and so that there will only be one vertical scroll wheel for the whole page. Can such a solution be done with only HTML+CSS, or will some javascript [w/jquery] be required?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think you need an iframe?

Comment: Then please tell! What else would you suggest?

Comment: Suggest for what?  You haven't specified what you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Well naturally if I have an iframe I'm trying to put a external page within my page.. Are there any alternatives to an iframe for doing this?

Comment: Yes, just include the data (or download it and then include it) with a simple server side include.

Comment: First, I think that would involve proxying it through my system (which would add some significant latency I think), second, does having a nested HTML tag within an HTML doc cause any problems, especially if the nested one has it's own set of stylesheets?

Comment: Well you'd want to process it if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this to be possible with CSS alone, but fairly simple with jQuery

```
var iframe = $("#my_iframe");
var iframeContents = iframe.contents()
iframe.css({
    height: iframeContents.outerHeight(),
    width: iframeContents.outerWidth()
});
```

working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MUQ8V/3/